# Extract data from a subsection of a file using Shell commands or Perl

Tags: perl, bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to extract information from a particular section of a file (under a certain point). More precisely, I want to be able to look for a keyword, for example "M2", and then find "Freq" under M2 to get that number without mixing up with M1 or M3.

Most likely the easiest answer would be a combination of grep, sed, awk or cut.

> M1{
>
> > Freq: 1GHz
> >
> > Temp: 125C
>
> }
>
> M2{
>
> > Freq: 1.1GHz
> >
> > Temp: 130C
>
> }
>
> M3{
>
> > Freq: 0.78GHz
> >
> > Temp: 89C
>
> }

Comment: If you can use awk, then it's pointless to use grep or sed or cur since awk can do all that and more.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about crowdsourcing script writing. The author makes no attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if /M2\{/ .. /\}/ and /Freq:\s*(.*)/' file
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){..}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `/M2\{/ .. /\}/`: Range operator to test for between two lines
- `/Freq:\s*(.*)/`: Find matching line, and capture value in `$1`.

Comment: Thanks @Miller. If you don't mind I'd like to extend my question for you. I hope you tweak your answer to fit my extension. What if instead of 
   "Freq: 1.1Ghz" 
I had: 
  "Freq: {
    CONDITION { f < 100 }
      FORMULA { f*2+f/2 }
    CONDITION { 100 =< f AND f < 100 }
      FORMULA { f*2/+f/3 }
  }
and want to get all those conditions and formulas (the number of conds/frmls may vary). I basically want to get them and use the conditions as real if-else conditions in Perl and also use the formulas as real return values.

Comment: Freq: { \n CONDITION { f < 100 } \n FORMULA { f*2+f/2 } \n CONDITION { 100 =< f AND f < 100 } \n FORMULA { f*2/+f/3 } \n }

Comment: APPRECIATE YOUR PROMP CONSIDERATION. Wish we had more people like u here!

Comment: This is basically a weird script that I want to turn some parts of it into real Perl script --of course after finding the right subsection and reading it correctly. I know how to do further manipulation. 'm very novice.

Comment: @user3761870 Comments are not a useful place for expanding a problem when you also have data to share.  I suggest that you add an edit to the bottom of your original question.

Comment: Sure, I'll do it shortly. Just a quick check: Shouldn't this work for capturing "{ f < 100 }" in the modified question: 
perl -ne 'print $1 if /M2\{/ .. /\}/ and /Freq.:\s\{/ .. /\}/ and /CONDITION\s*(.*)/' file ?

Comment: This perl one-liner is currently doing line by line processing.  Therefore any regex that attempts to match across lines is going to fail.

Comment: I asked it as another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461292/extracting-multiple-subsections-of-a-file-in-perl I look forward to hearing from you. Thanks a ton @Miller

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
awk '/M2/ {found=1} found && $1=="Freq:" {print $2; exit}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use awk,

```
$ awk -v RS="\s*M" 'NR==3{print $3}' file
1.1GHz
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane 'print $F[1] if /M2[{]/ .. /[}]/ and /Freq/' file
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj tnx for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it with `perl`

```
perl -nle 'chomp; $str.="$_"; END{ $str =~ /M2\{.*?(Freq: .*?\s)/ && print $1 }' file
Freq: 1.1GHz
```

Explanation:

1. `chomp` removes `\n`
2. `$str.="$_"` creates a string with the whole input
3. `$str =~ /M2\{.*?(Freq: .*?\s)` Extracts the field we're after