# Extracting multiple subsections of a file in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following script and want turn some parts of it to Perl script. The parts that I'm interested in are very similar to perl and easy to convert (FYI: `COND` and `FORMULA` mean `if` and `return` in Perl, respectively). However, I'm struggling to extract these sections properly.

```
... #OTHER STUFFS
K K1 {
... #MORE OTHER STUFFS
    LOL {
        COND { d < 0.01 }
        FORMULA { -0.2 + 3.3*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.01 }
        FORMULA { -0.2 + 3.3*sqrt(d+0.4) }
    }
... #MORE OTHER STUFFS
}
... #OTHER STUFFS
K K2 {
... #MORE OTHER STUFFS
    LOL {
        COND { d < 0.03 }
        FORMULA { -2.2 + 1.3*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.03 }
        FORMULA { -2.2 + 1.3*sqrt(d+0.8) }
    }
... #MORE OTHER STUFFS
}
... #OTHER STUFFS
K K3 {
... #MORE OTHER STUFFS
    LOL {
        COND { d < 0.02 }
        FORMULA { -4.3 + 0.3*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.02 }
        FORMULA { -4.3 + 0.3*sqrt(d+0.3) }
    }
... #MORE OTHER STUFFS
}
... #OTHER STUFF
```

I've tried the following perl-liner,

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if /K\sK2\s\{/ .. /\}/ and /LOL\s\{/ .. /\}/ and /COND*(.*)/' filename
```

to extract, for instance, `{ d < 0.03 }` from

```
K K2 {
... #MORE OTHER STUFFS
    LOL {
        COND { d < 0.03 }
        FORMULA { -2.2 + 1.3*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.03 }
        FORMULA { -2.2 + 1.3*sqrt(d+0.8) }
    }
... #MORE OTHER STUFFS
}
```

But

1. It failed and I don't know how to fix it
2. How I can fix it in a way to be able to catch the second `COND` statement in the same section
   (i.e. `COND { w >= 0.03 }`). In other word, how I can skip the first, second,... occurrence of a string.

PS If I can get this extraction part done, I know how to convert it to Perl-looking code

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/release/TBONE/Parse-RecDescent-FAQ-7.5/lib/Parse/RecDescent/FAQ/Original.pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the conditions, and translate them into anonymous subroutines that can be eval'd and then assigned to a hash.

You will want to test the below thoroughly before using, as I don't know your full data set.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our %formula_per_k;
INIT {
    # List all functions that you want to allow in formulas.  All other words will be interpretted as variables.
    my @FORMULA_FUNCS = qw(sqrt exp log);

    # Load the data via a file.
    my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

    # Parse K blocks
    while ($data =~ m{
        ^K \s+ (\w+) \s* \{
            ( (?: [^{}]+ | \{(?2)\} )* )         # Matched braces only.
        \}
    }mgx) {
        my ($name, $params) = ($1, $2);

        # Parse LOL block
        next if $params !~ m{
            LOL \s* \{ 
                ( (?: [^{}]+ | \{(?1)\} )*? )    # Matched braces only.
            \}
        }mx;
        my $lol = $1;

        # Start building anonymous subroutine
        my $conditions = '';

        # Parse Conditions and Formulas
        while ($lol =~ m{
            COND \s* \{ (.*?) \} \s* 
            FORMULA \s* \{ (.*?) \}
        }gx) {
            my ($cond, $formula) = ($1, $2);

            # Remove Excess spacing and translate variable into perl scalar.
            for ($cond, $formula) {
                s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
                s{([a-zA-Z]+)}{
                    my $var = $1;
                    $var = "\$hashref->{$var}" if ! grep {$var eq $_} @FORMULA_FUNCS;
                    $var
                }eg;
            }

            $conditions .= "return $formula if $cond; ";
        }

        my $code = "sub {my \$hashref = shift; ${conditions} return; }";

        my $sub = eval $code;
        if ($@) {
            die "Invalid formulas in $name: $@";
        }

        $formula_per_k{$name} = $sub;
    }
}

sub formula_per_k {
    my ($k, $vars) = @_;

    die "Unrecognized K value '$k'" if ! exists $formula_per_k{$k};

    return $formula_per_k{$k}($vars);
}

print "'K1', {d => .1}   = " . formula_per_k('K1', {d => .1}) . "\n";
print "'K1', {d => .05}  = " . formula_per_k('K1', {d => .05}) . "\n";
print "'K3', {d => .02}  = " . formula_per_k('K3', {d => .02}) . "\n";
print "'K3', {d => .021} = " . formula_per_k('K3', {d => .021}) . "\n";


__DATA__
... #OTHER STUFFS
K K1 {
    LOL {
        COND { d < 0.01 }
        FORMULA { -0.2 + 3.3*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.01 }
        FORMULA { -0.2 + 3.3*sqrt(d+0.4) }
    }
}
... #OTHER STUFFS
K K2 {
    LOL {
        COND { d < 0.03 }
        FORMULA { -2.2 + 1.3*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.03 }
        FORMULA { -2.2 + 1.3*sqrt(d+0.8) }
    }
}
... #OTHER STUFFS
K K3 {
    LOL {
        COND { d < 0.02 }
        FORMULA { -4.3 + 0.3*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.02 }
        FORMULA { -4.3 + 0.3*sqrt(d+0.3) }
    }
}
... #OTHER STUFF
```

Outputs:

```
'K1', {d => .1}   = 2.13345237791561
'K1', {d => .05}  = 2.01370729772479
'K3', {d => .02}  = -4.13029437251523
'K3', {d => .021} = -4.13002941430942
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Miller. While I'm trying to understand your code myself, a little comment or explanation on complicated parts (of course in your spare time) will be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Wonderful @Miller! I'm gradually perceiving the greatness of your code. Is there an easy way (to add a piece of code) to print the perl code for conditions and returns instead of evaluating them? It seems simply "print $code" doesn't work. Sorry for bugging you way too much. I'm killing myself to do it in perl so that I can finally learn Perl. (I only know Python, C and Bash).

Comment: Please forgive me for making things complicated. I edited the original script by simply adding `... #MORE OTHER STUFFS` to the original script in order to make it more general. Please go ahead and edit your code in a way to cover this change as well. Thank you so much again. @miller

Comment: I've edited the regex in a way that might cover your roving spec.  I don't have anymore time for this until Monday though, so good luck with the studies.

Comment: Do you have any update or change to address the thing that I mentioned above. I basically want to print all `COND`s and `FORMULA`s listed under a any given `K`x. Thanks again @Miller

Comment: You are correct, my last minute before the weekend edits did not work.  I've corrected the update so that the regex will now work for your revised spec.  Note how I've separated out the parsing steps into 3 different regular expressions.  This simplifies things greatly, and makes the regexes a lot less fragile.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help man. So here is the scenario: I'm going to tune your code into what I want (of course after perceiving it) and then use it as a parser for a bigger programmer. Basically, this piece of code is supposed to read a script (kinda provided above) and then based on the inputs `K` and `d`, returns a new value for `d`(you most likely noticed that by looking at the script). So how do you advise me to do this? Should I make a separate routine out of it in a separate file and call it (with inputs `k` and `d`) from the main program or ...? @Miller

Comment: By returning a new value for `d`, I meant This code will return a value (based on inputs `K` and `d`, and of course `COND`s and `FORMULA`s) which is a new value for `d` that will be used in the rest of code. (Simply adjust the value of `d`). You don't really need to know this information, I just wanted not leave you with any confusion. --hope didn't.

Comment: Everything that you need is already included in the above code.  I already determine the value on 4 variations of K and d, so you'll just need to adapt this for your sub, yes.

Comment: Part of the greatness of your code comes from the smart hiring of `shift`. However, (since this was a simplified version of what I wanted) I'm now struggling to pass more than 1 variable to the subroutine. Lets say in addition to `d`, I have another variable (e.g. `q`) appeared in `COND` and `FORMULA`. How do you change this line of code: `my $code = 'sub {my $d = shift; ‘;`. (I think that I know how to change the other lines such as `die "Unrecognized variable in condition: $cond" if $cond =~ /(?!d)[a-zA-Z]/;` and `s/^\s+|\s+$//g, s/\bd\b/\$d/g for ($cond, $formula);`? accordingly) @Miller

Comment: I hard coded the d variable because that's the only one I saw, and because you had an unstated list of functions like sqrt.  You could just as easily make the anonymous function accept a hash reference of variable/value pairs.  Then one would just need to change the sub building regex to translate things into something like `$hashref->{d}`.  If you were really good, you'd actually make error checking by detecting the potential variable names, and ensuring the hashref only included them.  Anyway, this is all too much to do in a comment without real data.

Comment: I've updated the code to treat variable translation in a more global sense.  This changed the style of the function call as well, as there is no longer just a static d variable.

Comment: I wish I could upvote multiple times. Thanks a ton man. I also asked another question that you may also be interested to look at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519747/replacing-string-2-to-sqrt-string-in-perl (there is one answer already which confuses me a bit).

Comment: quick question: In order to handle different `COND`s I extended `while( $lol =~ m{ COND \s* \{ (.*?) \} \s* FORMULA \s* \{ (.*?) \} }gx )` to `while( $lol =~ m{ COND \s* \{ (.*?) \} \s* FORMULA \s* \{ (.*?) \} }gx  || $lol =~ m{ COND2 \s* \{ (.*?) \} \s* FORMULA \s* \{ (.*?) \} }gx)`. However, the program runs for ever (or I don't know). Any idea? How to implement it correctly? @Miller

Comment: how does `COND2` differ from `COND`?  If it's only a name difference, then simply adjust the regex to allow for it as well: `while( $lol =~ m{ COND2? \s* \{ (.*?) \} \s* FORMULA \s* \{ (.*?) \} }gx )`

Comment: It's just naming but totally different, like `COND` and `STATE`.

Comment: `while( $lol =~ m{ COND|STATE \s* \{ (.*?) \} \s* FORMULA \s* \{ (.*?) \} }gx )` didn't work either!

Comment: Ignore me for now, I think that I'm corrupting `$1` and `$2` by putting some log statements `print "LOG\n"`. I'll get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: To you use an or `|` like that, you need to put them in a non-capturing group: `while( $lol =~ m{ (?:COND|STATE) \s* \{ (.*?) \} \s* FORMULA \s* \{ (.*?) \} }gx )`

Comment: Hey @Miller Is there any way to bypass the error generated by `my $sub = eval $code;` and continue the rest of the code? I'm looping and calling this subroutine with different inputs and for some of them there are math errors (such as `Can't take sqrt of -0.04 at (eval 1) line 1`). I would like to pass on to the next call in these cases. Thanks. Don't bother yourself if it's too complicated; I have alternatives in my mind --just curious.

Comment: Any chance to get your attention on [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640201/extracting-boundaries-out-of-given-condition-in-perl) @Miller

Comment: what does on "1" mean?

Comment: My 1 is clickable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640201/extracting-boundaries-out-of-given-condition-in-perl

Comment: Ahh.  I actually voted to close that question because it doesn't show enough effort to solve the problem yourself.  However, I've posted a proof of concept that will perhaps enable you to get started at least.

Comment: That's cool. I'm 17 and new to stack overflow. I'm still learning how to ask my questions properly here :) Thanks for your helps anyway.

Comment: Yep, SO takes a little while to figure out.  I'm still working at it.  At minimum, I'd recommend you coming up with an actual Handle to be referred as.  Something so that it easier to connect with you as a person and be more likely to be invested in helping you become a better programmer.  And choose wisely.  Something like LazyNinja obviously discourages people from wanting to invest their time.

Comment: Hi @Miller I need an urgent help. I'd be very grateful if you can help me with this. I'm running my code on a machine with perl v5.8.9 and I can't update its perl. It complains about regex. How'd you rewrite `  while ($data =~ m{
        ^K \s+ (\w+) \s* \{
            ( (?: [^{}]+ | \{(?2)\} )* )         # Matched braces only.
        \}
    }mgx) {
        my ($name, $params) = ($1, $2);

        # Parse LOL block
        next if $params !~ m{
            LOL \s* \{ 
                ( (?: [^{}]+ | \{(?1)\} )*? )    # Matched braces only.
            \}
        }mx;` to work with perl v5.8.9

Answer (score 1):

First at all, sorry for the one-liner, but I use a readable way.

To extract the information you want (in general):

```
my $data = <<EOD;
... #OTHER STUFFS
K K1 {
    LOL {
        COND { d < 0.01 }
        FORMULA { -0.2 + 3.3*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.01 }
        FORMULA { -0.2 + 3.3*sqrt(d+0.4) }
    }
}
... #OTHER STUFFS
K K2 {
    LOL {
        COND { d < 0.03 }
        FORMULA { -2.2 + 1.3*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.03 }
        FORMULA { -2.2 + 1.3*sqrt(d+0.8) }
    }
}
... #OTHER STUFFS
K K3 {
    LOL {
        COND { d < 0.02 }
        FORMULA { -4.3 + 0.3*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.02 }
        FORMULA { -4.3 + 0.3*sqrt(d+0.3) }
    }
}
EOD

while( $data =~ /COND    \s* { \s* (?<cond>    [^}]*? ) \s* } \s* 
                 FORMULA \s* { \s* (?<formula> [^}]*? ) \s* }
                /xg ) {
    print "Condition: $+{cond}\nFormula: $+{formula}\n";
}
```

for a particular item, you can use:

```
if ($data =~ /K2 \s* { \s* LOL \s* { \s*
              COND    \s* { \s* (?<cond>    [^}]*? ) \s* } \s* 
              FORMULA \s* { \s* (?<formula> [^}]*? ) \s* }
             /x) {
    print "Condition: $+{cond}\nFormula: $+{formula}\n";
}
```

Note: I have build the patterns to automatically trim spaces that wraps "condition" and "formula", but if you want to preserve these spaces you can change `\s* (?<cond> [^}]*? ) \s*` to `(?<cond> [^}]* )` *(the same for "formula")*. Note that this change makes your pattern more performant.

---

If the item you contains several "LOL" parts, you can use the [`\G` feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) in a global research to obtain all the items:

```
my $data = <<EOD;
K K2 {
    LOL {
        COND { d < 0.02 }
        FORMULA { -2.1 + 1.2*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.02 }
        FORMULA { -2.1 + 1.2*sqrt(d+0.7) }
    }
    LOL2 {
        COND { d < 0.03 }
        FORMULA { -2.2 + 1.3*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.03 }
        FORMULA { -2.2 + 1.3*sqrt(d+0.8) }
    }
    LOL3 {
        COND { d < 0.04 }
        FORMULA { -2.3 + 1.4*sqrt(d) }
        COND { d >= 0.04 }
        FORMULA { -2.3 + 1.4*sqrt(d+0.9) }
    }
}
EOD

while($data =~ /(?:K2 \s* { | \G(?!\A) )\s* (?:LOL\d* \s* { \s* )? 
                COND    \s* { \s* (?<cond>    [^}]*? ) \s* } \s* 
                FORMULA \s* { \s* (?<formula> [^}]*? ) \s* } (?: \s* } )?
               /x) {
    print "Condition: $+{cond}\nFormula: $+{formula}\n";
}
```

Note: obviously, you must replace `LOL\d*` with a subpattern that matches all possible names.

Comment: It's important to know which conditions belong to which KX? I want to get for example the second condition of K2 (COND { d >= 0.03 }). @Ccasimir-et-hippolyte

Comment: In addition to "K Kx" you also ignored LOL, there might be different strings there that I'm not interested in. Very readable code tho! @Ccasimir-et-hippolyte It'd be great if you can change your code in a way that I described. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3761870: The last pattern gives you the first condition in the string for K2. If you have several K2 in the string and you want to find the formula for a specific condition, you can replace `(?<cond>    [^}]*? )` with, for example, `d\s*>=\s*0\.03`

Comment: @user3761870: `LOL` is in the last pattern too. I gaves you a general way to extract datas with the first pattern (that you can adapt to your specific case), the last pattern is for the specific case you show in your question.

Comment: Shoot, Sorry I totally missed that part. You're right. What if there are `LOL2` and `LOL3` aside `LOL` in the same subsections? @Ccasimir-et-hippolyte How do u generalize your code to embrace multiple `LOLx` as well. Thanks

Comment: I realized a bigger issue in your code. You code (for the "particular item") is not able to print the second, third,,, conditions in a subsection (e.g. `COND { d >= 0.03 } FORMULA { -2.2 + 1.3*sqrt(d+0.8) }` under `K2` or at least print all of them (the number of `COND` and `FORMULA` may vary).

Comment: Do you have any update or change to address the issue that I mentioned above. I basically want to print all `COND`s and `FORMULA`s listed under a any given `K`x. Thanks @casimir-et-hippolyte